# How to capture a column value in the Oracle Error Log Table while insertion fails?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, error-logging

I’m working on a project where we backup purged records and delete it from the main tables. This process involves multiple table purging.
I use ‘Insert into Select’ query to select and bulk insert into the backup tables and delete those records from source.
The errored out records captured in the Error log table. Note, we have one error log table per schema and not per individual tables.

For errored out records, Oracle inserts the row id in the error log table, and I need to capture other column details too in the log table.
The table structure looks like this,

```
CREATE TABLE error_log (
  ora_err_number$ NUMBER, 
  ora_err_mesg$ VARCHAR2(2000), 
  ora_err_rowid$ ROWID, 
  ora_err_optyp$ VARCHAR2(2), 
  ora_err_tag$ VARCHAR2(2000)
);
```

From the documentation, it seems we can use ora_err_tag$ to add customized information. I could do this like below,

Case 1:

```
update SCHEMA.TABLE_A set COL1 = 1234567890
log errors into SCHEMA.ERROR_LOG('ID:' || COL1) reject limit unlimited;
```

The above query stores the col1 value in the error log if the updation fails.

Case 2:
However, when I try to do using ‘Insert Into Select’ it says invalid identifier. I tried with alias too, but it doesn’t work.

```
INSERT into SCHEMA.TABLE_A(COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4) 
select COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4 from TABLE_A 
where COL1 in (select X from SCHEMA.PURGE_TABLE)
log errors into SCHEMA.ERROR_LOG('ID:' || COL1) reject limit unlimited;
```

Am I missing some syntax or we can’t capture the column value in this way? Any help much appreciated. Thanks!